# How to take number of bytes transmitted and received from /net/proc/dev

Tags: cat, proc, net

I want to take the number of bytes transmitted and received from `/proc/net/dev` in this format: `num_ofbytesTransmitted,num_ofbytesReceived`.
This was my approach:

```
cat /net/proc/dev | grep enp0s3 | cut -f5 -d' '
```

and

```
cat /net/proc/dev | grep enp0s3 | cut -f48 -d' '
```

but the problem here is that I can't always use these constants on cut since the numbers can get big and that number has to change... What can I do in these circumstances?

Comment: Quick tip: Drop `cat` and do `grep enp0s3 /net/proc/dev` instead.

Comment: @forest are you sure it's just that?

Comment: No, that's why it was a quick tip instead of an answer.

Comment: @forest I understand but I have no clue how to use your tip

Comment: Same homework over on AU: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094459/how-to-get-tx-rx-using-shell-script

Answer (score 1):

Use AWK instead:

```
awk -v OFS=, '/enp0s3:/ { print $10, $2 }' /proc/net/dev
```

This looks for lines matching “enp0s3:” in `/proc/net/dev`, and prints the tenth and second fields, separated by a comma.